# Looking for Harry Potter fan fic story w/ unique character Jamie Oliver

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I’ve read this story a few times along with its sequel. I was so sure I bookmarked it but unfortunately I had not.

The first story is set during *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* and Harry gets together with Viktor until the last few chapters, where a prank goes seriously wrong and Harry gets hurt by Viktor.  The unique character in this story is Jamie Oliver and his family.

The sequel continues to have Jamie in it, and the final pairing ends up being Charlie and Harry, with Bill and Tonks as a side pairing.

I know the writer had been editing and/or rewriting bits of it.

I think the titles were:

- *Surprise, Surprise*
- *Surprise continues*

but I have not been able to find hide nor hair of them.

It was on fanfiction.com.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Comment: Not this one; https://www.fanfiction.net/s/7392395/1/Surprise-Surprise

Comment: Not this one; https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2993844/1/Surprise-Surprise

Comment: “The unique character in this story is Jamie Oliver and his family” — as in the chef?

Comment: I know which story you mean. It is by Dutchgirl84. I don't think it is on fanfiction.net anymore though.

Comment: @RobinHendrickson - There's mention on google that [Surprise!, Surprise!](https://www.ficforums.com/index.php?topic=71117.0) (by Dutchgirl84) contains a scene where the characters visit a restaurant inspired by Jamie Oliver's Fifteen.

Comment: Harry Potter and The Turkey Twizzlers!

Answer (score 2):

You're right @RobinHendrickson, it was Surprise Surprise by Dutchie848.

It was removed by the author to later repost but was never reposted. But you can still read the series through the handy-dandy [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20171105060946/http://archiveofourown.org/works/12450516/chapters/28332552)